# Centroid of an irregular pentagon with variable sides

Tags: geometry

I would very much appreciate any help on this important question to my work. Suppose an irregular pentagon is formed by the combination of 5 variable parameters, as illustrated in the Figure. I know how to determine the centroid both geometrically and by the equations of areas and projections of sides. The problem that I have is this: Given the centroid xo, yo, is there another way of finding the same centroid (in Cartesian coordinates) if the sides A...E vary inside the region?
Really appreciate your thoughts.
[image]

Best wishes,
Luiz

Comment: Interesting question I may think about later. In the meanwhile, have you tried for a triangle and square? I suspect uniqueness for the triangle and not for square, pentagon, ...

Comment: Please read tags before using them - the algebraic-geometry tag you had applied to this question was not appropriate, and this information was included in the tag.

Comment: It is unclear how the pentagon is given using "five parameters". Above all you have not declared what your "centroid" is. Is it the centroid of the five vertices, or the centroid of the pentagonal area? Only for a triangle these are the same.

Comment: thank you all for your comments.

Comment: Clarification: the centroid is always formed by the proportioned components A...E.

Comment: the point is if you compensate the position of the red vertices can you change that and still keep xo,yo constant?

Comment: I realize that the centroid $G$ you are speaking about is defined by $\vec{OG}=\frac15(\vec{OA_1}+...+\vec{OA_5})$... Right ?

Answer (score 6):

We are going to show that there is no unicity : one can get the same centroid with different weights on the 5 axes.

Let $\alpha=2\pi/5$.

Let $M_k$ ($k=1,\cdots,5$) be the vertices of the regular pentagon on Fig. 1. ($M_1$ being the rightmost).

$\vec{V_k}:=\vec{OM_k}=\binom{\cos (k-1)\alpha}{\sin (k-1)\alpha} \ \  \text{for} \ \ k=1,\cdots 5\tag{1}$

We have :

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 \vec{V_k}=\vec{0} \tag{2}$$

Let us assume that a certain point $C$ is the barycenter (= centroid) of points $M_k$ associated with weights $a_k$ (non all zero), i.e.,

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 a_k\vec{V_k}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^5 a_k\right)\vec{OC}\tag{3}$$

Let us show that there is a different system of weights $a'_k$ such that one gets the same centroid, i.e.,
 :
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 a'_k\vec{V_k}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^5 a'_k\right) \vec{OC}.\tag{4}$$

**First case** : no constraint on weights.

(4) can be obtained by adding to equ. (3), equ. (2) multiplied by a certain positive quantity $\varepsilon$
with all $a'_k$ still $>0$. (one can even take $\varepsilon < 0$ if all $a_k>0$).

[image]

*Fig. 1 : An example with resp. weights $0.5,0.2,0.4,0.7,0.5$ on points $M_k$ giving the polygon represented in red with a certain (vertices') centroid $C$  (red star). In blue, different polygons sharing the same centroid $C$, the smallest one having $O$ as one of its vertices.*

---

**Second case :** Let us now assume that :

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 a_k\vec{V_k}=\vec{OC},\tag{3'}$$

with the following constraint :

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 a_k=1 \tag{5}.$$

(we will assume that all $a_k$s are $>0$)

Let us consider two of the numerous identities linking the $V_k$s, for example, the following ones :

$$\begin{cases}\vec{V_2}-c\vec{V_1}+\vec{V_5}&=&0 \ \  (a)\\
\vec{V_{3}}-c\vec{V_2}+\vec{V_{1}}&=&0 \ \ 
 (b)\end{cases}\tag{6}$$

where $c$ is a constant equal to $2\cos(\alpha)$.

(Please note that identity (6b) can be deduced from (6a) by a circular permutation).

Let us consider the identity obtained by subtracting (6b) from (6a) :

$$-(c+1)\vec{V_1}+(c+1)\vec{V_2}-\vec{V_3}+\vec{V_5}=0\tag{7}$$

with the important property that the coefficients' sum of this null linear combination is itself $0$.

If we now combine $(3')+\varepsilon \times$ (7), (for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small, as in the first case), we obtain :

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 a'_k\vec{V_k}= \vec{OC} \ \ \  \text{still with } \ \sum_{k=1}^5 a'_k=1\tag{8}$$

with at least some $a'_k \neq a_k$ (see Fig. 2).

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Initial pentagon (in red) with resp. weights $a_i$ $(0.25,0.20, 0.20,0.1,0.25)$ (sum = 1) and its center of gravity (marked by a little star). Other pentagons (different colors from red to blue) whose coefficients verify (8) for different values of $\varepsilon$ ; they all share the same center of gravity.*

In fact, I obtained this rather short proof by a linear algebra approach : I considered the $2 \times 5$ matrix with columns the $V_k$s ; its kernel $K$ is 3-dimensional (by rank-nullity theorem) ; a possible basis of $K$ is as follows (do you recognize the entries ?) :

$$U_1=\begin{pmatrix}-c\\1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}, \
U_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-c\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \
U_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-c\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\tag{9}$$

What we have done in (7) is to find a vector ($U_1-U_2$) belonging to the intersection of the kernel with the affine hyperplane $\sum_{k=1}^5 a_k=1$.

---

Here is a slightly more sophisticated approach to this second case providing, I think, a complementary geometrical understanding :

Let us gather coefficients into two groups, the left group $a_3, \ a_4$ and the right group $a_1, \ a_2, \ a_5$. In order to be better understood, let us assume that we have for example :

$$\underbrace{a_3, \ a_4,}_{a_3+a_4=0.4} \ \underbrace{a_1, \ a_2, \ a_5.}_{a_1+a_2+a_5=0.6}$$

i.e., we consider the cases where the 3 rightmost directions $\vec{V_1}$, $\vec{V_2}$ and $\vec{V_5}$ account together for $60\%$ of the total weight ; therefore, the 2 leftmost directions account together for $40\%$ of the total weight.

Let $\gamma_L$ (L like left) and $\gamma_R$ the left and right partial centroids, being understood that the global centroid (centroid of centroids) is given by :

$$c=0.4 \gamma_L + 0.6 \gamma_R$$

- The set of points  $\gamma_R$ is the green triangle (easy by thinking to barycentric coordinates) whose vertices represent extreme cases, for example ($60\%,0\%,0\%$) for $A_0$.
- The set of points  $\gamma_L$ is the red curve, which is a parabola (using the theory of quadratic Bezier curves : see the second animated figure in https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/maths-linear-quadratic-relations/0/steps/12129).

Now, let us take for example :

- $\gamma_R \ =$ the center 
  of gravity of the triangle (corresponding to weights $a_0=a_1=a_5=0.2$ otherwise said, each of the 3 right directions have absolute weight $20\%$),
- $\gamma_L$ such that $w^2$ has a weight 3 times the weight of $w^3$ (which means that the resp. absolute weights are $\tfrac34 40\% = 30\%$ and $10\%$).

Check : $20\%+20\%+20\%+30\%+10\%=100\%$

Now, keeping the same $c$, it is geometricaly clear that moving (progressively ?) point $\gamma_L$ into $\gamma'_L$ on the red curve, one will find a point $\gamma'_R$ still inside the triangle such that $c$ remains the weighted average of the new points  $\gamma'_L$ and $\gamma'_R$ with resp. weights $0.4$ and $0.6$. See Fig. 3.

[image]

*Fig. 3 : Point $C$ is the weighted average of the partial centroids $\gamma_L$ and $\gamma_R$ with weights $0.4$ and $0.6$ resp. but as well of $\gamma'_L$ and $\gamma'_R$ with the same weights.*

Comment: I understand Jean Marie. The only problem with the kind of "concentric" if you like pentagons is that the proportions of the 5 axis changes... Remember in the original question I mentioned proportioned sides.. that means the sum of all sides must add up to 1. For example, if one side increases in proportion another one has to reduce to keep up the sum total. Agree?

Comment: Many thanks for the effort and help Jean Marie.

Comment: OK, but recognize you should have said it more explicitly : "proportionned sides" does not mean necessarily that we deal with percentages adding up to 100% ; moreover, on your example (red pentagon) they add up to something like 200%...

Comment: Much appreciate your thoughts and demo. Best regards,

Comment: I have written the new Edit taking into account the constraint of sum = 100%. I confirm that non only there is no unicity, but we can even say that the same centroid can be obtained in an infinite number of ways. I can give precisions on the two techniques used (barycentric coordinates and quadratic bezier curves).

Comment: +1, more if I could. Note that some of the pentagons aren't even convex. I wonder if there's a unique one that's a quadrilateral, separating the convex and nonconvex instances.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Thanks for your comments about the first part (the second part uses very different arguments). I hadn't thought to these aspects (separation convex/nonconvex and also 4 axes instead of 5).

Comment: Much appreciate the brilliant demonstration and to learn about the incredible work of Bezier and his counterpart. Your answer brought us light! Have a wonderful weekend. Luiz Cheim

Comment: To illustrate the reason why I need this. In the electricity industry, particularly in the condition assessment of power transformers, we utilize a diagnostic tool to analyze the presence of electrical or thermal faults in transformers based on the combustible gases dissolved in the insulating oil (commonly mineral oil). The most recent and sophisticated tool is call Duval Pentagon that you can find information about here http://www.transformator.ptpiree.pl/konferencje/transformator/2017/materialy/21.pdf

Comment: I want to convert the complex geometry of the Pentagon into a simple Artificial Neural Network trained with real or synthetic data to provide the same diagnostic as the geometry but with simple input output type of program, simpler logic. My problem was this: Suppose I create a synthetic combination of all 5 gases that fall in a given region of the Pentagon. Their proportions add to 1, as explained before. Are there other combination of gases that could lead to the same diagnostic? (the position of the centroid). And more, are those other combinations meaningful in practical terms? dilemma.

Comment: By the way, the "creator" of the method Michel Duval is a French man that immigrated to Canada in the 80s. He is still around and a very nice friend that I will meet next week in a transfomrer conference in the IEEE, Anaheim, CA

Comment: Very interesting precisions. Above 3 variables, rendering percentages in a meaningful and useful way is not evident ! I wasn't aware of the work of Michel Duval. There are other ways to cope with this : for example using special coordinates like Sibson coordinates that you can discover in the nice recent document https://team.inria.fr/titane/files/2017/03/barycentric.pdf

Comment: I have simplified the presentation of the first part.

Comment: After many attempts I have arrived at a rather simple and didactical proof of case 2