# geometric center of points located on a regular polygon

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a regular 7 sided polygon. I have one point on each side of this polygon. The points cannot be on the vertices.

Can the geometric center of these 7 points also be the geometric center of another set of  7 points also located on the edges (vertices excluded) ?

<s>Intuitively, I would say "no" because the number of edges is odd so points cannot be budged symmetrically, I would also think that the result shouldn't depend on the number of sides as long as it is odd</s>

So the answer is "Yes". (see answers from jean Marie and Marty cohen)

**Question 2 (asked by Marty Cohen and actually is the one I should have asked)**: what happens when the angles between consecutive lines from the center of the polygon to the 7 points are arbitrarily specified (the only restrictions being that they are positive and total 2π) ? Or if at least one of these angles is different from others ?
Or in other words what happens when there is no symmetry between the points ? Does the "Yes" answer still hold ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say intuitive "yes" as you have $2$ degrees of freedom for the centre but $7$ degrees of freedom for the points on the sides

Comment: Take points at the center of each side.

Comment: Consider a 7-spoke figure consisting of the polygon vertices each joined to their geometric center. Rotating this arbitrarily about the center will produce a set of intersection points, one on each edge, and any such set has the same center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes" (even if one excludes the elementary cases depicted in my first answer, and by a certain number of us).

Let $A_k$ ($k=0,\cdots 6$) be the vertices and $P_k$ the points on line segment $[A_k,A_{k+1}]$ (with a modulo 7 convention).

We have:

$$\underbrace{\frac17 \sum \vec{OP_k}}_{\text{c. of mass of points} \ P_k}=\underbrace{\frac17 \sum \vec{OA_k}}_{\text{c. of mass of points} \ A_k  \ = \ O}+\frac17 \sum \vec{A_kP_k} \tag{1}$$

Let

$$v_k:=\vec{A_kP_k} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \vec{V}= \sum \vec{A_kP_k} \tag{2}$$

As a consequence of (1); the two centers of mass coincide if and only if

$$\vec{V}=0 \tag{3}$$

This is possible in a myriad of cases, as the following graphical representation shows. Indeed (3) is possible if and only, with the $v_k$s, one can built an heptagon of a special kind (irregular sidelengths and regular angles; i.e., all its internal angles are equal) with a "head-to-tail" loop representation (like in statics).

[image]

Such heptagons can be obtained graphically as the intersection of strips with variable width (or, if one prefers, of half-spaces) having polar angles $k \dfrac{2 \pi}{7}$. Slightly moving these strips in a orthogonal direction give different heptagons, i.e., different set of points $P_k$.

Now that we have understood the idea, a rigorous construction of any case is made possible by incremental construction. Here is how:

Let us assume that points $P_k$ are referenced by their abscissas $a_k$ defined by $\vec{A_kP_k}=a_k \vec{A_kA_{k+1}}.$ We will also consider that the sides have unit length.

- 0. Start with any case for values $a_k$ (for example all $a_k=1/2$ (midpoints)).
- 1. Make a choice of a certain index $k$ and a certain (small) value $d$.
- 2. change $a_k$ into $a_k+2d$ (the abscissa is either augmented of shortened according to the sign of $d$).
- 3. change  $a_{k-1}$ into $a_{k-1}-d/\cos (2\pi/7)$.
- 4. change  $a_{k+1}$ into $a_{k+1}-d/\cos (2\pi/7)$.

Then iterate the process 1)+2)+3)+4) (of course one has to check that abscissas always remain in the range $[0,1]$).

Remarks :

1. Angle $2\pi/7$ above is the so-called "external angle" of the heptagon.
2. A similar question could have been asked for any regular $n$-gon.
3. A question of the same type related to a general triangle (not equilateral in general): [Coinciding centroids of two triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307356/coinciding-centroids-of-two-triangles).
4. As remarked by @dxiv, this center of mass preservation is not limited to the case where this center is $O$. It can be applied to any center of mass.
5. I end with a simulation result showing where centers of mass of points $P_k$ can be situated for random positions of these points on the sides (purple points) and for extreme cases where points $P_k$ are situated on some $A_k$s (red points).

[image]

**Remark:** A cousin issue, asked for a pentagon instead of a heptagon, is to be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3156107).

Comment: Thanks @Jean Marie , do you believe (intuitively) that it is possible given  7 points on the edges of this polygon to construct an 8th point  belonging to the plane or 3D space, that has this property of being uniquely defined by the  7 points ?

Comment: My first intuitive answer is that it looks impossible for dimensional issues ; indeed fixing the abscissas of points on the 7 sides is like fixing a point in a 7-dimensional space, more exactly in the 7-dimensional hypercube. Even with an added 8th information, it looks me impossible to assign a unique point in a 2D plane...

Comment: @JeanMarie May be worth noting that the algebra works the same in any vector space, so when all $a_k$ are equal the centroids coincide if for example $A_k$ are $7$ arbitrary points in 3D, not necessarily the vertices of a regular heptagon in the plane.

Comment: @dxiv You are right .

Answer (score 3):

If the lines from
the center of the polygon
to the points on the sides
have the same angle
between consecutive lines
($2\pi/n$),
the resulting polygon
will again be regular
so its center
will be the same as the
original one.

I will leave it to others
to work out what happens
when the angles between
consecutive lines
are arbitrarily specified
(the only restrictions being that
they are positive
and total $2\pi$).

Comment: Hi, The question you ask is the one I wanted to ask without even knowing it @marty cohen. Are you saying that the answer is obvious ?

Comment: Nope. I'm working that out now. I will probably submit it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** have the same the same center of mass.

Here is a counter example.

Let us take the notation $P_k, \ k=0\cdots 6$ for the vertices (modulo 7: for example $P_7=P_0$).

Conider the family of points $Q_k:=\frac23 P_k + \frac13 P_{k+1}$ (points situated at the limit of the first third on each side ; notations that can be understood with complex numbers for example) and the family of points $R_k:=\frac13 P_k + \frac23 P_{k+1}$  (points situated at the beginning of the last third on each side).

The $Q_k$ family has center of mass at the origin (proof: $\frac17 \sum (\frac23 P_k + \frac13 P_{k+1})=\frac17(\frac23 \sum P_k + \frac13 \sum P_{k+1}) = 0+0$).

Same computation for the other family $R_k$ : they share the same center of mass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if you break the symmetry ? what happens if at least one point is not allowed to be on the "same" place as other points (here all of your points are situated at the limit of the first third of each side for example)

Comment: it is true that this solution has a certain "symmetry". I saw some days ago a similar question for a general (not equilateral) triangle, and the only solution was like the one I have proposed you. I am going to look for it.

Comment: 1) Here is the [equivalent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4307356) for a triangle that I just mentionned. 2) I have been interested by the connection you make with quantum physics, but it is far from my expertise field. Nevertheless, I am going to make some simulations to better understand what happens.

Comment: See my second answer, where I show that if you take the same proportion between successive point (yours is 2/3) the center remains the same. I also give an example where taking different proportions results in a different center.

Answer (score 2):

I am submitting this
second answer
since it is completely algebraic.

I show

(1) if the angular spacing
between the lines
is the same then
the derived polygon
(defined below)
has the same center
(this does not depend
on the original polygon
being regular)

and

(2) if the angular spacing
linearly increases then
the centers are not the same.

The points on a $n$-gon are
$(z_k)_{k=1}^n$.
Given
$(r_k)_{k=1}^n$
with
$0 < r_k < 1$
let
the derived points
$(w_k)_{k=1}^n$
be
$w_k
=r_kz_k+(1-r_k)z_{k-1}
$
with
$z_0 = z_n$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n w_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (r_kz_k+(1-r_k)z_{k-1})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n r_kz_k+\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^nr_kz_{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n r_kz_k-\sum_{k=1}^nr_{k+1}z_k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n (r_k-r_{k+1})z_k\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $r_k=r_{k-1}$
for all $k$,
the derived points
have the same center.

Also,
if the polygon is regular,
so
$z_k
=e^{2\pi i k/n}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n w_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^n r_kz_k+\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^nr_kz_{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n r_k(z_k-z_{k-1})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n r_k(e^{2\pi i k/n}-e^{2\pi i(k-1)/n})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^n r_ke^{2\pi i (k-1)/n}(e^{2\pi i /n}-1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nz_{k}+(e^{2\pi i /n}-1)\sum_{k=1}^n r_ke^{2\pi i(k-1)/n}\\
\end{array}
$

so the derived center
is the same as the original center
if and only if
$S(r)
=\sum_{k=1}^n r_ke^{2\pi i(k-1)/n}
=0
$.

For example,
suppose $r_k = k/n$,
so the spacing gradually increases.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
S(r)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (k/n)e^{2\pi i(k-1)/n}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n ke^{2\pi i(k-1)/n}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1}
\qquad x=e^{2\pi i/n}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\dfrac{n x^{n + 1} - (n + 1) x^n + 1}{(x - 1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\dfrac{T(r)}{U(r)}
\qquad T(r)=n x^{n + 1} - (n + 1) x^n + 1,
U(r)=(x-1)^2\\
\\
T(r)
&=n x^{n + 1} - (n + 1) x^n + 1\\
&=x^n(nx-(n+1)) + 1\\
&=e^{2\pi i n/n}(ne^{2\pi i/n}-(n+1)) + 1\\
&=(ne^{2\pi i/n}-(n+1)) + 1\\
&=n(e^{2\pi i/n}-1)\\
&\ne 0
\qquad\text{for } n > 1\\
U(r)
&=(x-1)^2\\
&=(e^{2\pi i/n}-1)^2\\
\text{so}\\
S(r)
&=\dfrac1{n}\dfrac{T(r)}{U(r)}\\
&=\dfrac1{n}\dfrac{n(e^{2\pi i/n}-1)}{(e^{2\pi i/n}-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac1{e^{2\pi i/n}-1}\\
&\ne 0
\qquad\text{for } n > 1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Just to be sure, in your answer the $z_k$ seem to be the vertices of the polygon ? so if I understand correclty what you show in (2) is that the geometric center of any set of points with linearly increasing $r_k$ is not the polygon center ? @marty cohen

Comment: That is correct. I work with the $r_k$ because it was easier (to me) than working with the angle increments.

Comment: I have written a "graphical proof" showing that we have a huge degree of freedom for providing "irregular" solutions. Of course, this can be given an algebraic "translation"... not far from yours.